# How to update arrays in res/values/array.xml by code?

Tags: android, xml, arrays, string, resources

I can use

`Resources res=this.getResources();

          arr1=res.getStringArray(R.array.one);`

to get the array and changed some of its values,

Then how can I save the new values back to the file of `res/values/array.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "save the new values". Resources are read-only at runtime.