# Add new values to existing resource array

Tags: android, arrays, xml, resources

I have a res/values String-array that I would like users to be able to add new elements to via a form.  I saw a post from 2011 that asked this question ([How to update arrays in res/values/array.xml by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227549/how-to-update-arrays-in-res-values-array-xml-by-code)) however, the answer stated that resource arrays are read-only at run time.  I was wondering if anything has changed since 2011 that would allow users the ability to update the resource array (add new strings to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately resource values are still immutable. They are generated when your project is compiled and overriden on every compilation. There is a corresponding warning here in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Thank you Dr. Nedolya - any ideas for a work around? I know you could do it with a db connection - but I kind of wanted to keep it stand-alone

Comment: @MichaelCarolan You can also try to store your array in SharedPreferences, like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android/7361989#7361989 Another option is to store your data in standalone file which would be placed in your app's private directory.